# org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to get browser

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am logging in to my application (IE browser). On Home page, it has consumer link. I am clicking it.. It will open another window.. Enter the consumer id (mandatory field alone) and save. It is getting saved.

Now If I wanted to view the saved consumer. I need to close the window and need to transfer the control to Home page. I am trying by `driver.switchTo.defaultContent()` after closing the window. But it is NOT changing the control. the below error is returned..

**Exception**:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to get browser (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

**Code**:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;

public class FirstTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        File file = new File("IEDriverServer.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
        WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();        
        driver.get("http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx/mysuite/Login.aspx");
        driver.findElement(By.id("txtUser")).sendKeys("administrator");
        driver.findElement(By.id("txtPwd")).sendKeys("password");
        driver.findElement(By.id("cmdLogin")).click();      
        //Click Add customer (customer child window opens)
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Add Customer")).click();
        driver.switchTo().window("Customer");
        //Enter Customer ID and Save
        driver.findElement(By.id("txtCode")).sendKeys("1234");
        driver.findElement(By.id("cmdPageSave")).click();
                //Close the child window
        driver.findElement(By.id("cmdPageClose")).click();
        //swith back to parent window
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("All customers")).click();




    }

}
```

Comment: Are you doing this in the same tab or two tabs?

Comment: does your window gets refreshed when u click the consumer link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try storing handler name before switching.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        File file = new File("IEDriverServer.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
        WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();        
        driver.get("http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx/mysuite/Login.aspx");
        driver.findElement(By.id("txtUser")).sendKeys("administrator");
        driver.findElement(By.id("txtPwd")).sendKeys("password");
        driver.findElement(By.id("cmdLogin")).click();      
        //Click Add customer (customer child window opens)
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Add Customer")).click();

        //Store before switch    
        String  mainHandle= driver.getWindowHandle();

        driver.switchTo().window("Customer");

        //Enter Customer ID and Save
        driver.findElement(By.id("txtCode")).sendKeys("1234");
        driver.findElement(By.id("cmdPageSave")).click();
                //Close the child window
        driver.findElement(By.id("cmdPageClose")).click();
        //swith back to parent window

        driver.switchTo().window(mainHandle);

        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("All customers")).click();

    }
```

Comment: This is i have tried.. NO such window expection is thrown