# What to do when org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to get browser is displayed?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11

It is not working even changing the IEDriver.

I tried with windows update as it solves many problems, even that did not help me.
The same test case runs on `IE9` and `IE10`, but not on `IE11`.

How do I handle this? The problem persist on both 64 bit as well as 32 bit machine.

Comment: Please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29671372/org-openqa-selenium-nosuchwindowexception-unable-to-get-browser) to see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Show your line of code.Set the protected mode same for all zones, either enabled or disabled. Preferred would be enabled. See [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/63141-internet-explorer-protected-mode-turn-off.html)

Comment: I have all the 4 check boxes enabled under security tab.

Comment: @BeforeMethod
 public void setUp() throws Exception {

  DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
  cap.setJavascriptEnabled(true);

  this.driver = new FirefoxDriver(cap);
  this.driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
  this.driver.manage().window().maximize();
  
  System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", System.getProperty(
       "webdriver.ie.driver", "./BrowserDrivers/IEDriverServer.exe"));
    driver1 = new InternetExplorerDriver(cap);
     driver1.manage().window().maximize();
     
  this.driver1.manage().deleteAllCookies();
 }

Comment: This is the before method, here i launch 2 browsers 1 is IE and another is Firefox. First part of script runs on Firefox and then the script continues on IE.

Answer (score 0):

Create instance for Firefox and Internet Explorer browsers.

Try below code:

`

```
@BeforeMethod 
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(cap);
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", System.getProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "./BrowserDrivers/IEDriverServer.exe"));
    WebDriver driver1 = new InternetExplorerDriver(cap);
    driver1.manage().window().maximize();
    driver1.manage().deleteAllCookies();
}
```

`

Comment: I have instantiated the driver and driver1 as 
___***public WebDriver driver, driver1;___***

Comment: If you have instantiated the driver and driver1, then your code should work.I had executed on my machine it is working without any errors. Try to use latest 32-bit IEdriver.

Comment: We execute a precondition that runs on firefox first, it run for a period of 3-5 minutes. After that the test case execution starts on IE. there I am facing this issue., If the script launches directly on IE I am able to execute. But what I want is, IT SHOULD  RUN ON IE AFTER THE PRECONDITION IS DONE ON FIREFOX.

Comment: Please show your precondition code that runs on Firefox first and  the test case code for IE

Comment: I am sorry, due to security reasons I cannot show you my script. But the scenario is :
We launch firefox and IE together in our BeforeMethod
Then We run a part of our script on FF
And then it launches the application URL on IE and the script execution starts.. But since I upgraded to IE 11, My scripts are failing when the script has to start on IE